# How to override exported function from R package listed in Imports

Tags: r, namespaces, httr, r-package

[My package](https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j)'s `DESCRIPTION` file has `httr` in its Imports directive:

```
Imports:
    httr (>= 1.1.0),
    jsonlite,
    rstudioapi
```

`httr` [exports an S3method](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L15) for `length.path`.

```
S3method(length,path)
```

And it's [defined as](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/2b09b32a9acdb1ca40543ed05576516b1264c887/R/write-function.R#L88):

```
#' @export
length.path <- function(x) file.info(x)$size
```

In my package I have objects that I assign the class "path" to. Every time I assign the class "path" to any object, regardless of whether or not I ever call `length()` on the object, this is printed to stdout:

```
Error in file.info(x) : invalid filename argument
```

Here's some reproducible code everyone can run:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1

> thing = 1:5
> class(thing) = 'path'

> requireNamespace('httr')
Loading required namespace: httr

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1  R6_2.1.2    tools_3.3.1

> thing = 1:5
> class(thing) = 'path'
Error in file.info(x) : invalid filename argument
```

I've tried catching it in a `try` but that doesn't work:

```
set_class = function(obj, c) {
  class(obj) = c
  return(obj)
}

thing = 1:5
thing = try(set_class(thing, 'path'), silent=TRUE)
```

Yields:

```
Error in file.info(x) : invalid filename argument
```

I've tried `assignInNamespace` to override the function:

```
base_length = function(obj) {
  return(base::length(obj))
}

assignInNamespace('length.path', base_length, 'httr')
thing = 1:5
class(thing) = 'path'
```

But I get `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`

When I use `httr` functions in my package I use them with `httr::function` so I'm not sure how this `length.path` function is leaking into my namespace and overriding the base length function. I've also tried explicit `@importFrom httr function` for each function that I use instead of using `httr::function` but that doesn't work either.

I also found this:

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/79059/

But the solution seemed to be to edit the source code of `httr`, which I can't do since my package imports it. How can I get around this?

Comment: If `length()` is a generic, then you want to call `base::length.default()` to get the default method.

Comment: The problem is I never call length. This happens when I call class(obj) = 'path'

Comment: I think `class(obj) = 'path'` only gives an error within RStudio or similar IDEs where you can can basically see the output of `str(...)` for your workspace variables all the time. When you assign a new class the IDE updates this description and calls `length` in the process. In the "normal" RGui the error does not occur.

Comment: Ahh that must be it, then. Still, I should be able to override that function somehow, right?

Comment: You should complain to the author of the method because overriding length in that way is a really bad idea! (ie. file an issue on GitHub and we'll fix it in httr)

Comment: Creating an issue to change it did cross my mind but I figured there must be some way for me to manage the namespaces of the packages my package imports. Asking a maintainer to change something every time there's a conflict doesn't seem very scaleable. Anyway, I created the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be to create a function `length.path()` in your own package. If the base type of your `path`-objects is compatible with `base::length()` you could just unclass it to avoid infinite recursion:

```
length.path <- function(x) length(unclass(x))
```

However, this is potentially slow compared to a direct call to `base::length()` because it copies the object and needs method dispatch two times.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. Added that verbatim to my package and still seeing the error to stdout. Do I need to export it perhaps? The base type of my path object is a list, so I think it should work fine.

Comment: Are you sure the error is created by the `Imports: httr` in the DESCRIPTION file? I just tried to create a dummy package that imports httr and contains just one function that returns an object of class `path`. Everything works. Only when I call `library(httr)` after loading the dummy package the error arises.

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen until I use a function in my package that uses `httr`. So if I library(RNeo4j) and then sessionInfo(), `httr` namespace isn't loaded, but as soon as I use a function from my package that uses `httr::func` internally, I see `httr` in sessionInfo(). And that's when I can reproduce the file.info error.

Comment: Of course, my bad -.-  exporting the above function with `export("length.path")` works for me. Declaring it as `S3method("length", "path")` does not.

Comment: Still not working. :( I have the function in my NAMESPACE under export(length.path) and still seeing the error to stdout.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it was mostly your `unclass` idea that got me through but I've added an answer for what worked for me specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add an `.onLoad` function. Thanks to [AEF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185171/how-to-override-exported-function-from-r-package-listed-in-imports/39185868#39185868) for the `unclass` idea.

```
#' @importFrom utils assignInNamespace
.onLoad = function(libname, pkgname) {
  length.path = function(obj) {
    return(length(unclass(obj)))
  }

  assignInNamespace('length.path', length.path, 'httr')
}
```

It raises a `NOTE` in `R CMD check --as-cran` but I'm hoping to get away with it.